# Install Istio in multi master nodes in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I read about Istio and I need to install it in Kubernetes.

I don't know what is the best way to install Istio in a multi-node Kubernetes cluster.

The setup is multi-node master cluster and multi-node slave for Kubernetes.

Is the best way to install with Istio multicluster or sidecar injection (automatic)?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference on how many Master and Slave Nodes your Kubernetes cluster has if you want to install Istio.

You can follow the instructions from this [link](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/quick-start/)

Briefly, you need to:

1. Download Istio [release](https://github.com/istio/istio/releases)
2. Install Istio’s Custom Resource Definitions using `kubectl apply -f install/kubernetes/helm/istio/templates/crds.yaml` from that release
3. Install Istio components using one of options:

   - without mutual TLS authentication between sidecars using `kubectl apply -f install/kubernetes/istio-demo.yaml`
   - with default mutual TLS authentication `kubectl apply -f install/kubernetes/istio-demo-auth.yaml`
   - [Render Kubernetes manifest with Helm and deploy with kubectl](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/helm-install/#option-1-install-with-helm-via-helm-template)
   - [Use Helm and Tiller to manage the Istio deployment](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/helm-install/#option-2-install-with-helm-and-tiller-via-helm-install)

For auto injection, you need to install `istio-sidecar-injector` component and add `istio-injection=enabled` label for a Namespace in which you want it to work. 
Example of commands:

```
kubectl label namespace <namespace> istio-injection=enabled
kubectl create -n <namespace> -f <your-app-spec>.yaml
```